# Warning: Error in ggplot: You're passing a function as global data. Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

The data is from [here](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2022_per_game.html). I selected the "Get table as CSV (for Excel)" option from "Share & Export". I highlighted all the resulting table text, and copied to excel. I then did "Text to columns" and split the data by the comma delimiters. I then saved the file as a .csv extension. My goal is to create an app with sliders for minutes and games played with a check box for teams. I want plotly graphs with pop ups. When I run my code I'm getting an error where my graphs should be stating: "Warning: Error in ggplot:   You're passing a function as global data.Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()`". My code is below. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

Player_Stats<-read.csv("2021-2022 Indiv Per Game Stats.csv")
colnames(Player_Stats)[11]<-"FG%"
colnames(Player_Stats)[14]<-"ThreeP%"
colnames(Player_Stats)[17]<-"TwoP%"
colnames(Player_Stats)[18]<-"eFG%"
colnames(Player_Stats)[21]<-"FT%"     
ui<-fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Player Stats"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          sliderInput("input1",
                      "Minutes",
                      min=0,
                      max = 48,
                      value = 0),
          sliderInput("Input2",
                      "Games Played",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 82,
                      value = 0),
          checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "tm_input",
                             label = "Team",
                             choices = unique(Player_Stats$Tm),
                             selected = unique(Player_Stats$Tm))
        ),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("plot1"),
          plotOutput("plot2"),
          dataTableOutput("Player_StatsTable")
        )
      )
    )
    
    server<-function(input, output){
      output$plot1<-renderPlotly({
        x<-Player_Stats %>% ggplot(aes(x=PTS, y=`ThreeP%`,color=Tm,
                                                text=paste("Player:",Player, "PPG:",PTS, "3P%:", `ThreeP%`*100, "Team:",Tm)))+
            geom_point()+
            xlab("Points per Game")+
            ylab("Three Point %")+
            ggtitle("PPG and 3P% by Player")+
            theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
        ggplotly(x)
      })
      output$plot2<-renderPlotly({
        y<-Player_Stats %>% ggplot(aes(x=PTS, y=`TwoP%`,color=Tm,
                                             text=paste("Player:",Player, "PPG:",PTS, "2P%:", `TwoP%`*100, "Team:",Tm)))+
            geom_point()+
            xlab("Points per Game")+
            ylab("Two Point %")+
            ggtitle("PPG and 2P% by Player")+
            theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
        ggplotly(y)
      })
      Player_Stats=reactive({
        Player_Stats %>% 
          dplyr::filter(Tm %in% input$Tm_,.preserve = TRUE) %>%
          dplyr::filter(MP>=input$input1) %>% 
          dplyr::filter(G>=input$input2)
      })
      output$Player_StatsTable<-renderDataTable({
        Player_Stats
      })
    }
    shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: First problem: reactive values need to be called as functions, i.e. `y <- Player_Stats() %>%`. Second problem: the reactive expression thinks Player_Stats is a reactive expression and not the static dataframe Player_Stats. Change the name of one to disambiguate the two.  Third problem: in your filters change `input$Tm_` to `input$tm_input` . Fourth problem: for some reason the initial value for input1 and input2 is NULL, it needs to be 0, otherwise the filter doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I see why `input$input2` was returning `NULL`. Ids are case sensitive. In the input slider change `Input2` to `input2`.